# Date formatter inside DIV tag

Tags: javascript, html, vaadin, lit

```
     <div>
        <strong>Date: </strong>
        ${dateInUtc}
     </div>
```

This dateInUtc **(2021-12-09T15:43:29+01:00)** contains the date in UTC format.
Need to format it like this **2021-12-09 - 15:43:29**.

How do achieve this without using external libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the required format is close to what you already have you can do this quite simply without having to parse the date in the first place.

```js
const dateInUtc = `2021-12-09T15:43:29+01:00`;

const formattedDate = dateInUtc.replace(`T`, ` - `).split(`+`)[0];

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: If we pass the date in another format we can't do that. like:
Input: 
`new Date().toUTCString().replace(`T`, ` - `).split(`+`)[0]`
Output:
`Fri, 22 Jul 2022 09:21:42 GM - `

Comment: @ArtBindu I did prefix the answer with _"Because the required format is close to what you already have"_. If this solution doesn't work for you then check out the duplicate I linked 8o)

Comment: Also, you could use `.toISOString()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any framework then use Datapipe in that framework.

Example: [Datepipe-Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

If you are not using any framework then use the date format utility function like:

```
df = (function(d) {
    d = new Date(d);
    return `${d.getFullYear()}-${(d.getMonth()+1).toString().replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&')}-${(d.getDate()).toString().replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&')} - ${(d.getHours()).toString().replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&')}:${(d.getMinutes()).toString().replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&')}:${(d.getSeconds()).toString().replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&')}`;
});
console.log(df(new Date().toUTCString()));
```

Output:

```
'2022-07-22 - 14:41:36'
```

Explanation:
This is the objective to get data from the Date object.

```
    d = new Date(d);
    obj = {
        date: d.getDate(),
        month: d.getMonth(),
        year: d.getFullYear(),
        hour: d.getHours(),
        minute: d.getMinutes(),
        second: d.getSeconds()
    }
```

I am using regular expression `str.replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&')` or `str.replace(/^[0-9]{1}$/g, '0$&')`to add an addition zero if data is a single digit.
Like:

```
'0'.replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&') // '00'
'8'.replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&') // '08'
'12'.replace(/^[0-9]$/g, '0$&') //'12'
```

Comment: Why are you taking a date and formatting it (string) and then parsing it again. Why not just pass the date to `df`

Comment: According to the question, pass some dates in UTC format. It's not mandatory ...